# How to submit emr jobs from separate ec2 linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I would like to know how to execute emr jobs & redshift copy commands from a separate ec2 linux instance?

Configuration:
2 eme ec2 running (one for master & one for Task)
1 ec2 linux instance
1 ec2 windows

I am able to execute jobs (s3 file movement, emr script residing in s3, Hard code copy commands to load into redshift]from  ec2 windows (donwloaded aws cli).

Regards
Sanjeeb

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [EMR CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/index.html) to [submit a step](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/add-steps.html).

[Here's](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/add-steps-cli-console.html) more documentation from the EMR docs on how to do this.